# How do I resolve the "inconsistent chromosome block error?

Tags: bioinformatics, samtools

I am trying to align reads to hg38 using bowtie2 and then samtools. After getting the bam files and trying to index them I got the error:

```
E::hts_idx_push\] Chromosome blocks not continuous \[E::sam_index\] Read 'SRR764959.25000002' with ref_name='NC_000001.11', ref_length=248956422, flags=0, pos=91387388 cannot be indexed samtools index: failed to create index for "HFFmerged.bam": No such process
```

I am a complete novice to the whole process of analysing such data. I am using a MacBook Air and tried using `fastq-dump` to convert some `sra` files to `fastq`, then I split them using

```
split -l 4000000 input.fastq output_prefix
```

and trimmed them with `trim-galore`. After indexing `hg38` to `bowtie2`, I used the first block of code below to align my reads and then converted my `sam` files to `bam` with `samtools`. After merging all the `bam` files together I tried to index the merged `bam` file to `samtools` but got the error:

```
E::hts_idx_push\] Chromosome blocks not continuous \[E::sam_index\] Read 'SRR764959.25000002' with ref_name='NC_000001.11', ref_length=248956422, flags=0, pos=91387388 cannot be indexed samtools index: failed to create index for "HFFmerged.bam
```

```
for file in /Volumes/Untitled/IPStrimmed/*.fq; do
    output=$(basename "$file" .fq).sam
    bowtie2 -x /Volumes/MACOS/Users/rafail/Downloads/HG38/hg38_index -U "$file" -S "/Volumes/Untitled/IPStrimmed/IPSsam/$output"
done
```

Comment: Please include in your question the samtools commands that resulted in the error.

Comment: Possibly related: [https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/13997/samtools-index-chromosome-blocks-not-continuous](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/13997/samtools-index-chromosome-blocks-not-continuous)